# Jquery : add title to jquery data table( retrieving from server side)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I add title to jquery data table dynamically. title is retrieve from server. Sorry, I sense this might be basic but i've been banging my head against it.

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/DataTables

Basically i want to add title in between "show entities" and search textbox.
Any suggestions / pointers ?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control DOM elements that are generated by the datatable using the sDom settings:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'l<"toolbar">frtip'
} );
```

This way you can put some div with some class e.g. "toolbar" (syntax is <"toolbar"> in the example above) and create script that will put the content of the div e.g.:

```
$("div.toolbar").html('<b>This is my custom title</b>');
```

See http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html as an example.

Comment: @JocaPC : Its giving me error as `javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /pages/layout/homeLayout.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 22] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup`

Comment: Try to put it in the external js file and include it as a script. It seems that your server side parser cannot handle this syntax.